# Do I have to travel with her at all cost?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration

I applied to travel together with my wife to the UK for holidays, we have been granted the visa but something else has come up and I have to travel somewhere else, can she travel alone and I join her there later after my meeting, or do we have to travel together?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, you don't have to travel together.  Your visas were approved on their individual merits and entitle you to travel together or separately.

Of course, it would be wise for both you to bring along documentation that showed what happened since the visa approved, namely your business trip and changed flights.